# Enable/Disable HashiCorp Terraform condition constraint block inside statement depending on expression value

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, terraform

I have a terraform statement with multiple condition blocks and I need to enable / disable one of them based on condition:

```
statement {
 sid = "..."
 effect = "Deny"
 actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
 condition {
  # ...
 }
 condition {
  test = "ArnNotEquals"
  variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
  values = [var.needed_arn]
  # I need to have an expression which turns on / off the current condition like this
  # enabled = var.environment == "dev" ? true : false
 }
}
```

Is it possible to do it somehow? If not - maybe there's a way to turn on / off the statements?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide complete example of your policy, how and where do you use it?

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achive that using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
statement {
 sid = "..."
 effect = "Deny"
 actions = ["s3:PutObject"]
 condition {
  # ...
 }

 dynamic "condition" {

    for_each = var.environment == "dev" ? [1] : []

    content {
      test = "ArnNotEquals"
      variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
      values = [var.needed_arn]
    } 
 } 
}
```